# To represent equalities and inequalities, what is considered idiomatic Fortran?

Tags: fortran

Is it more idiomatic to use the usual

```
a < b
x == y
```

and so on or is

```
a .lt. b
x .eq. y
```

used more frequently?

Sometimes I'm not sure what is idiomatic and what is just legacy from the punchcard era when using Fortran, and this is probably the one case I have not found an answer for yet.

Comment: .lt., .eq. are the only one available in fortran 66 and 77. Fortran 90 standard  added the <, ==, etc. Both are valid. Personally, I prefer <, ==. But since most fortran user are from old school, you will mostly find the .lt. in most codes. That said, the most modern coding style is flourishing with the form that are common to other languages: <, ==, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, the choice is stylistic only, and I don't think the community has agreed that one is better. The 'modern' operators (`<`, `==` ...) were introduced in the fortran 90 standard so both have been around for a while.

It's worth noting that logical operators (`.NOT.`, `.OR.` ...) are formatted similarly to the legacy relational operators (`.NE.`, `.LT.` ...). So one can choose to mix-and-match:

```
 ((a < 1.0) .AND. (a > 0.0))
```

or be consistent:

```
 ((a .LT. 1.0) .AND. (a .GT. 0.0))
```

I personally prefer the modern form, particularly in these cases, because it helps to distinguish between logical and relational operators.

It also seems to me that `(dif < tol)` is easier to quickly understand than `(dif .LT. tol)`, particularly for the casual or fast reader.

I'm curious too, though - will other people have different preferences? Perhaps somebody can reference a fortran style guide that has an opinion.

Interestingly, a common fortran reference for me ([PGI Fortran](http://www.pgroup.com/doc/pgifortref.pdf), page 11) lists all the modern operators in a table, uses an example with a single legacy operator, and doesn't make mention of any of the other legacy operators.

Comment: I don't see any reason to use the old form. It is much less readable for me.